# model.__unicode__() returning russian string cause TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django, unicode, ascii

code:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'галерея'
        verbose_name_plural = 'галереи'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Галерея %s' % self.title
```

error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/galleries/gallery/
Caught an exception while rendering: ('ascii', '\xd0\x93\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x8f ', 0, 1, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
return u'Галерея %s' % self.title
```

Comment: This is the number one Django error I see. Rule of thumb: `__unicode__` must *always* return unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Because self.title is a unicode string and your string literal is not (its type is str), when Python executes the expression `'Галерея %s' % self.title`, it needs to coerce the string literal into unicode before performing the interpolation. It needs a character encoding to do this, and by default resorts to ASCII, which can encode less than 128 different characters.

To avoid this problem, use a unicode string literal : `u'Галерея %s'`. When in doubt, your strings should be unicode strings, especially in Django.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid errors like this, put it at the beginning of your file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```